# Measuring study area of elevational ranges in raster file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, area, elevation, calculate

I have a DEM layer with elevation ranges of -413-5593 m, just as seen below.

[image: Elevation dem map]

Then I determined the altitude between 4100 and 5400 m using symbology and band rendering, got the map below and the following black dots.

[image: Points or areas that are above 4100 meters high.]

Now I want to measure these points (The range of altitude that is between 4100 and 5400 meters), How can I calculate the area of these parts??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create contour polygons with 100 m interval
2. I had to fix geometries for next step to work (If you want to be able to calculate each single part polygons area also execute [Multipart to Singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts))
3. Add geometry attributes.

[image]

This will create a polygon layer with an attribute of each 100 m intervals area. Select the intervals you want and use Statistics panel to calculate the sum:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Bera ,How can I choose a part of these sections that I want? For example, I want to calculate only a part of those zone (image 1) and I want to exclude the separated parts from the calculations?

Comment: [Multipart to Singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgismultiparttosingleparts) prior to Add geometry attributes